# Listing events by categories and show category meta info (The Events Calendar)

Tags: the-events-calendar

I'm currently setting up events in the Events Calendar plugin and need to create a (supposedly) simple list.

The list should show those details:

- a "category header" showing the title, description and cost of the first event from that category (since those details are the same for all of the events within the same category)
- all events from that category sorted by date

I tried achieving this by using this code on a page template: https://gist.github.com/herrherrmann/1bf98addf711fcb4d2d9

The problem: the "category header" does not fit to the event list, instead it shows the data from the previous loop. Example:

> ~1st loop~
>   title: none
>   description: none
>   cost: none
>   all events from 1st category
>
> ~2nd loop~
>   title: title from 1st category
>   description: description from 1st category
>   cost: cost from 1st category
>   all events from 2nd category

I understand that I'm using the get_posts function in a wrong way and maybe I have to use two loops in order to get what I need? But I currently can't think of a pattern that outputs it correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know you want only the first one and you're not using a *typical* loop, you're already using an array of posts, you can just do 
    setup_postdata($events[0]);

and then get your data from the first item here

then continue your loop as written if it's working as happily as expected.

Comment: That sounds like the right track but adding `setup_postdata($events[0]);` in line 27 doesn't change anything.

Comment: ... and the reason is that I had to put `setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $events[0] );` - just as it is told in the (very good) [function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata)!